# Only one object in an array is drawn

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm trying to learn Monogame / XNA by creating a little Terraria-like game. I currently want to create a world, which is completely filled with dirt. My problem is that only one block from an block array gets drawn. Here is my code:

```
public class Survival2DGame : Game
    {
        private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
        private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;

        private World world;

        private Block dirtBlock;

        public Survival2DGame()
        {
            _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            IsMouseVisible = true;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            dirtBlock = new Block(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Dirt"), Vector2.Zero);

            world = new World(100, 100);

            WorldGeneration.GenerateWorld(world, dirtBlock);

            Debug.WriteLine(world.blocks[50, 50].Texture);
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            _spriteBatch.Begin();

            world.Draw(_spriteBatch);

            _spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
```

```
static class WorldGeneration
    {
        public static void GenerateWorld(World world, Block dirtBlock)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < world.Length; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < world.Height; y++)
                {
                    world.blocks[x, y] = dirtBlock;
world.blocks[x, y].Position = new Vector2(x * 16, y * 16);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
class World
    {
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }

        public Block[,] blocks;

        public World(int length, int height)
        {
            Length = length;
            Height = height;

            blocks = new Block[length, height];
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            foreach (Block block in blocks)
            {
                block.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
class Block
    {
        public Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
        public Vector2 Position { get; set; }

        public Block(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position)
        {
            Texture = texture;
            Position = position;
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Position, Color.White);
        }
    }
```

When i run the game its completely empty.

I think it has something to do with me only creating one dirt block and not a new one everytime i add it to the array. I so far only have experience with unity and there i would handle this with Scriptable Objects.

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle bug in your game, but the critical issue is in your code for `WorldGeneration.GenerateWorld()`

In your implementation, you have done

```cs
static class WorldGeneration
    {
        public static void GenerateWorld(World world, Block dirtBlock)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < world.Length; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < world.Height; y++)
                {
                    world.blocks[x, y] = dirtBlock; // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
                    
                    world.blocks[x, y].Position = new Vector2(x * 16, y * 16);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You see, in C# all class instances are [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types), meaning when you do `world.blocks[x,y]=dirtblock` for all iterations, **All of your instances are referring/pointing at the same instance `dirtblock`**.

To explain the above step by step, let's say the dirtblock instance is allocated in memory location `0x10`. In the first iteration (`x=0, y=0`), the following is executed:

```cs
world.blocks[0, 0] = dirtblock;
```

Then `world.blocks[0,0]` is also at the same location `0x10`. At this point, changing the value `dirtblock` or the value of `world.blocks[0,0]` would change the same variable. So at the end of the iteration, `dirtblock` and  `world.block[0, 0]` has their `Position` variable at `(0, 0)`

In the next iteration, `world.blocks[0, 1]` is also assigned to the same memory location, and its `Position` is made to be `(0, 16)`. But this also means that `world.blocks[0, 0]` and `dirtblock`'s Position value is made to be `(0, 16)` since all these variables are pointing at the same reference.

At the end of the entire loop, all blocks in your code have their `Position` value the same as the `Position` value of the last block, i.e `world.blocks[99, 99]`. Since this is outside the dimension of the game (i.e 640x480) You don't see anything.

So to get your code working, make a new memory instance for every block, as shown:

```cs
    static class WorldGeneration
    {
        public static void GenerateWorld(World world, Block dirtBlock)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < world.Length; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < world.Height; y++)
                {
                    world.blocks[x, y] = new Block(dirtBlock.Texture, new Vector2(x * 16, y * 16));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you can keep the world generation code unchanged, and have the `Block` as a struct instead of a class, and that will work just as you expect.

```
struct Block
{
    ....// Rest of the code unchanged
}
```

This will work because now `Block` is a value type, and on each assignment, a new instance is automatically created.

I recommend you to give [this article](https://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) a read for some more info on value and reference types in C# if this is a new topic for you. You only need to read up to the first 3 headings ("Introduction", "First, What Are Structs?", "Value and Reference Types").